# Testing triggered sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

We implemented standard triggered sends between SalesCloud and Marketing Cloud using Marketing Cloud Connector. 
When the Sales User creates a custom object's record, the trigger will send the email through Marketing.
Our aim is to see the email preview using customer data (e.g. firstname, lastname and so on) in the personalization strings before sending the email. We could alternatively send the email to our email address, but at the moment we didn't find any ampscript function that could fulfill this requirement.

Do you have any suggestions or possible workaround?
Is there a way to test triggered sends from SalesCloud to Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you could test this:

1. If you have the salesforce custom object record in Marketing cloud Data Extension using Import/Synchronisation, use the Email content preview with that Data extension.
2. If you donot have the salesforce record in a sepreate data extension, in the triggered send creation process, you should have created a data extension that holds the triggered send data. Goto Contact builder and update the sample data as like Salesforce in that data extension and use it in Email Content preview.
3. As always, if you are allowed to create a custom object record, create a sample record in Salesforce so that you can test triggered send as well.